# How can I create a continous For Loop within a Java program until a condition is met?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I wish to create a continuous Enhanced For loop within a Java program to output a message from an automatic ping to a Text area, and then to stop when a condition is met (IP address is offline). I have IP addresses in a String array called 'ip'. Works fine with no loop but requires continuous iterations until no response is detected.

Tried using Boolean loop which I included with the code - however does not append text to the TextArea and gets caught in a continuous loop.

```
        for (String ip : listOfhosts) {

        boolean repeatLoop = true;


        try {
            InetAddress i = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
            textArea.append("Sending Ping Request to " + ip + "\n");

            //boolean run = true;
            //while (run){

            if (i.isReachable(100)) { // 1 second limit
                textArea.append("Host is online \n");
            } else {
                textArea.append("\nHOST IS OFFLINE\n");
                //System.exit(0); //If something is offline, system will close. For now.   


                try {

                    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("email@gmail.com"));
                    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("email@hotmail.com"));
                    message.setSubject("Test Mail");
                    message.setText("Test Mail," + "\n Sent From sendMail.java application\n");
                    //textArea.append("OK - Online \n");

                    Transport.send(message);

                    textArea.append("Mail Sent to email@email.com \n host " + ip + " is offline \n");

                    return;

                } catch (MessagingException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }        
        } catch (Exception e) {
            textArea.append("Unknown HOST\n");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }while(repeatLoop);
```

Gets caught in continuous loop - crashing the program. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

This code will block you UI. You should run it in a separate thread, and also add some delay between checks.
A simpler solution would also be to use a Timer

For instance, to check every second:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // your code
    }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

There're two simple ways to break out of an enhanced for-loop in Java. One is to throw an exception, although for normal flow control this is considered exceptionally poor use of exceptions.

The other is to use `break;` which will break you out of the most immediate for-loop. People aren't always fond of `return` mid-function or `break` mid-for loop (or `continue` for that matter) as they can act a bit like goto/jump statements and reduce the clarity of your code. On the other hand, this is exactly what break is intended for, so there's no argument about misuse of the instruction.

An alternative approach is to use a normal while loop and forgo the enhanced for-loop for a normal iterator. In this case, `listOfHosts.iterator()`, will allow you to calculate a combination of `.hasNext()` and `isReachable(...)` to decide whether to continue looping.

Answer (score -1):

```
// suppose listOfhosts is a String Array
List<String> srcHostList = new ArrayList<String>();
srcHostList.addAll(Arrays.asList(listOfhosts));

List<String> offlineList = new ArrayList<String>();

while( srcHostList.size() > 0) {
    offlineList.clear(); 
    for(String ip: srcHostList) {
       boolean isOnline = true;
       try{
         // TODO check online
       }catch(Exception ex){
         // TODO handle exception
         isOnline = false;
       }
       if(!isOnline) offlineList.add(ip);
    }
    srcHostList.removeAll(offlineList);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the response, Java does not appear to recognize the 'removeAll' command. Any alternative suggestion?

Comment: "removeAll" is a method of java.util.List . https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)

 I suppose listOfhosts is List<String>. obviously it's not. so can you tell me what is listOfhosts?

Comment: Thanks. It is a String array containing 4 IP addresses and a URL. I feed them into the loop to check for connectivity and display the results in a text area. I wish for it to continue looping through until it finds no response then exits loop.